# TIEHTTP component doesnt work with IE9

Tags: delphi, http

I try to use TIEHTTP component in my Delphi application but got some problem. My application runs fine in XP with IE8 but it doesn't work in Windows 7 with IE9 (it return a page but without logging in).

I've tried Delphi 7 d2007 and D 2009 - same problem.

I did a search about the problem and found that solution, but it doesn't work!

http://www.myfxboard.com/tiehttp/discussion?id=4273

So I don't know what to do! Please help how to fix this in IE9!

```
//iehttp1.http_agent_string := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1092.0 Safari/536.6';
//iehttp1.content_type := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' ;

iehttp1.RequestMethod := 'POST';

iehttp1.ExecuteURL('http://www.example.com/act=login&login=[user]&password=[pass]');

memo1.Text  := iehttp1.result_sl.Text;
```

Comment: if request method is POST, shouldn't username and password be in the body of the request, and not in the url? also, shouldn't password also have '=' present?

Comment: @eis it can be the body or in the header, with HTTP Basic Authentication, the user and encrypted password information would be in the request header part for example.

Comment: query parameters start with a question mark and a list of query marks uses & as separator, so `/act=login&login=[user]&password=[pass]'` should be `/act=login?login=[user]&password=[pass]'`

Comment: Or as `/?act=login&login=[user]&password=[pass]`, depending on what the server is actually expecting. I suspect this latter case

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer doesn't support username and password in URL from security update 832894, here are the details :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

I don't have any experience with this component, but try using username and password property:

```
iehttp1.username := 'user1';
iehttp1.password := '*****';
```

as noted on [examples page](http://www.myfxboard.com/tiehttp/)

**UPDATE**

I was wrong, as mjn noted in comment this had nothing to do with your case, The IE change is for URLS like user:pass@example.com

Comment: i have found the solution i should put the data in iehttp1.postStr  thanks guys for your time

Comment: You should write that in answer and accept it for future reference

Comment: i cant answer my own quetion because i have less than 100 reputation i will be able to answer later(5 hours)

Comment: oh yes, I forgot about that, sorry

Comment: The IE change is for URLS like http://user:pass@example.com, while the question is about query parameters - which are not blocked by IE